# ReactJs - Call Second Function Parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using React-Bootstrap now, and I want to use the tooltip, but, I don't want to create 2 functions for the tooltip. So, I'm using the second parameter for changing the text of tooltips. But, I can't call it, the function read that I'm calling the first parameter, so, how to make the function to understand that I'm using the second parameter?

```
//this is my custom tooltip function

function renderTooltip(props, text) {
  return (
    <Tooltip id="button-tooltip" {...props}>
      {text}
    </Tooltip>
  );
}

const Example = () => (
  <OverlayTrigger
    placement="right"
    delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }}
    overlay={renderTooltip('hover me 1')}
  >
    <Button variant="success">Hover me to see</Button>
  </OverlayTrigger>

 <OverlayTrigger
    placement="right"
    delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }}
    overlay={renderTooltip('hover me 2')}
  >
    <Button variant="success">Hover me to see</Button>
  </OverlayTrigger>
);
```

Thank You mastah

Comment: `how to make the function to understand that I'm using the second parameter` By passing two parameters. Why don't you pass the props as well ?

Comment: Do you even use `<renderTooltip>` ? if now, why do you need a `props` parameter ?

Comment: Hi guys, I'm just following this ex, https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't try to remove the props, and it's clear and work, thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you are using props from your react component (this.props), you dont need to specifically pass them with function parameters.
You could use something like this:

```
function renderTooltip(text) {
  return (
    <Tooltip id="button-tooltip" {...props}>
      {text}
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

Comment: undefined has no property

Comment: Hi F, what do you mean using this.props?

Comment: Where is `props` defined then ? the function is outside of the component

Comment: Sorry that I didn't try to remove the props before, and it's clear and worked, thank you

Comment: No problem. Please click the "tick" button to accept my answer for others :)